# I have a question about the filter and url route

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjJZX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaaPo.png)

The above code is for filter (classification), and I think when state1 is selected, a specific theme is created depending on whether state2 is selected or not, and when state1 is not selected, a specific theme is linked.

The problem here is that only the url in state1>state2>they form is output. For example, clicking them and clicking state1 disables them and results in the selection of state1.
What I want is

1. theme > state1 > state2
2. state1 > theme > state2
   In this way, I want url generation and result output regardless of the click order.

I tried many times earlier, but I failed repeatedly.
I think it's because the existing code conflicts with the ones I tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating links completely, just add the data if available, like so:

```php
$theme_href = G5_BBS_URL."/board.php?bo_table=$bo_table";
if($state1)
    $theme_href .= "&state1=$state1";
if($state2)
    $theme_href .= "&state2=$state2";

$theme_option = "<td";
if($theme == "")
    $theme_option .= " class=\"on\"";
$theme_option .= "><a href=\"$theme_href\">...</a></td>";

//...
```